# Microsoft Offline Data Sync Columns Id

Tags: c#

I am using the Offline data sync library and am trying to avoid using a string as an identifier.

While investigating I came across this post [text](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/issues/371) which suggested a possible workaround.

I implemented the below class to use on my tables instead of the builtin EntityTableData class.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work because the data sync framework makes queries on the Id property which causes an unmapped column exception.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync.EFCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using KeyAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute;

public abstract class DataSyncTable : EntityTableData
{
    [NotMapped]
    public override string Id
    {
        get => MyId.ToString("N");
        set => MyId = Guid.Parse(value);
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guid MyId { get; set; }
}
```

The MappedTableRepository class in the Automapper version is now available however I can't work a way to use this to get around the string identifier.